# Remove blank page after frontmatter and start first chapter page numbering with one

Tags: page-numbering, blank-page, front-matter

Can anyone help me with starting page counting from one on the first page of my first chapter? I have really tried a lot of approaches but I simply do not get behind what the reason for this strange behavior is. Sorry for the messy MWE.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{\color{black}{page I \thepage}}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize{\leftmark}}\hspace{20mm}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{page\enspace I\enspace\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%  
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\chaptername\ \thechapter\enspace I\enspace{##1}}}{}}
}

% Remove empty page after TOC
    \renewcommand\mainmatter{%
       \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tables}

\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Example text via Lipsum}
\lipsum[3-5]
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-9]
\subsection{SubSection title}
\lipsum[10-13]
\subsubsection{SubSubSection title}
\lipsum[14-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the code really compile for you? I get errors about undefined control sequences

Comment: It does compile in Overleaf

Comment: It cannot compile in overleaf, because either `xcolor` or `color` package is missing

Answer (score 1):

The additional page was caused by a stray `\hspace{20mm}` in the mainmatter pagestyle which was used outside of all fancy header/footer definitions.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{\color{black}{page I \thepage}}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize{\leftmark}}%
%\hspace{20mm}%
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{page\enspace I\enspace\thepage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%  
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\chaptername\ \thechapter\enspace I\enspace{##1}}}{}}%
}

% Remove empty page after TOC
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
    \clearpage%
    \pagestyle{mainmatter}%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tables}



\mainmatter
\chapter{Example text via Lipsum}

\lipsum[3-5]
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-9]
\subsection{SubSection title}
\lipsum[10-13]
\subsubsection{SubSubSection title}
\lipsum[14-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, it does remove the awkward blank page in front of my chapter but then the pagestyle mainmatter is not applied aftwerwards ...

Comment: @Jonas Included the mainmatter paige style